# Jenkins remove special characters from environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have the following environment variable fixed in the Declarative Pipeline of Jenkins.

```
environment {
    branch = "${GIT_BRANCH}"
}
```

Unfortunately my branch consists partly of special characters as example

> feature/asldasd-asdasd

How can I remove these special characters like / in the declarative pipeline and then use the variable normally ?

```
        steps {
            echo '%branch%'
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace the character before using it. Check the example below.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    branch = "feature/asldasd-asdasd"
    }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
            branchName = env.branch.replaceAll('/', '')
            echo "$branchName"
            
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```